# Managed Metadata field each value to display on a new line

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, column, page-layout, managed-metadata

I have added a managed metadata column to my content type and have proceeded to add it to the page layout.  It is set to multi-value and is working fine with the delimiter as ";".

The results appear as follows:

```
a; b; c; d; e
```

Is is possible via the use of UI, CSS or JavaScript to make this field display each value on a new line, as opposed to in-line, i.e.

```
a;
b;
c;
d;
e
```

Comment: Please tag SharePoint version. How you added the field to the page layout?

Comment: SharePoint 2013 on-prem.  I added the field to the page layout through the use of SharePoint Designer 2013 by dragging my custom content field from the tool box on to my page layout.

Comment: Can you post your HTML DOM elements of that page? That way easy to identify what type of CSS or JavaScript code we need to apply.